# The JavaScript model design patterns, custom event and more

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, callback, javascript-objects, iife

> Given the following API:
>
> ```
> var person = new Model({name: 'John'});
> person.get('name'); //=> 'John'
> person.set('name', 'Johny');
> person.on('change', function(oldModel, newModel){
>     console.log(oldModel, newModel);
>     //=> {name: 'John'}, {name: 'Johny'}
> });
> ```
>
> **Write the Model class.**
>
> Specifications:
>
> 1. Model class has 3 methods: get, set and on.
> 2. Multiple "change" callbacks can be registered
> 3. All the callbacks registered need to be called when a change happens
> 4. A change event happens whenever new attributes are added or changed, via set method.

For this design question. I implemented in three different ways below.
They are all works.

My question is, which one is better? or why the one over the others?
Or if you have better solution, please help me to better understanding the concept behind the question.

IIFE

```
/** method 1: IIFE */
const IIFEModel = (function() {
  function ourModel(obj) {
    this.oldModel = Object.assign({}, obj);
    this.newModel = obj;
  }

  ourModel.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
    this.oldModel = Object.assign({}, this.newModel);
    this.newModel[key] = value;
    this.on("change");
  };

  ourModel.prototype.get = function(key) {
    console.log(this.newModel[key]);
    return this.newModel[key];
  };

  ourModel.prototype.on = function(eventName, handler = () => {}) {
    switch (eventName) {
      case "change":
        return handler(this.oldModel, this.newModel);
      default:
        return handler();
    }
  };

  return ourModel;
})();
```

Revealing Prototype Pattern

```
/** method 2: Revealing Prototype Pattern */
const PrototypeModel = function(obj) {
  this.oldModel = Object.assign({}, obj);
  this.newModel = obj;
};

PrototypeModel.prototype = (function() {
  const set = function(key, value) {
    this.oldModel = Object.assign({}, this.newModel);
    this.newModel[key] = value;
    this.on("change");
  };

  const get = function(key) {
    console.log(this.newModel[key]);
    return this.newModel[key];
  };

  const on = function(eventName, handler = () => {}) {
    switch (eventName) {
      case "change":
        return handler(this.oldModel, this.newModel);
      default:
        return handler();
    }
  };

  return {
    get: get,
    set: set,
    on: on
  };
})();
```

***** UPDATE THE CODE after @obfish suggestion******

```
/** method 3: ES6 */
class ECMAModel {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.oldModel = Object.assign({}, obj);
    this.newModel = obj;
    this.events = new Map();
  }
  set(key, value) {
    this.oldModel = Object.assign({}, this.newModel);
    this.newModel[key] = value;
    this.fire("change", this.oldModel, this.newModel);
  }
  get(key) {
    console.log(this.newModel[key]);
    return this.newModel[key];
  }
  on(eventName, handler) {
    if (this.events.has(eventName))
      this.events.set(eventName, this.events.get(eventName).concat(handler));
    else this.events.set(eventName, [handler]);
  }
  off(eventName, handler) {
    if (!this.events.has(eventName)) return;
    let index = this.events.get(eventName).indexOf(handler);
    if (index != -1) this.events.get(eventName).splice(index, 1);
  }
  fire(eventName, ...args) {
    if (!this.events.has(eventName)) return;
    if (!args || !args.length) args = [];

    var es = this.events.get(eventName),
      l = es.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      es[i].apply(null, args);
    }
  }
}
```

```
/** test case */
let person = new PrototypeModel({ name: "john" });
person.get("name");
person.set("name", "johny");
person.get("name");
person.on("change", function(oldModel, newModel) {
  console.log(oldModel, newModel);
});
```

And I notice that the way I create the custom event is little bit infeasible. Since I assuming that the callback function from the test has two elements, which might have a problem if considering scalability. Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: I have to say that you misunderstand the meaning of `on` method. If you know a bit of DOM, `on` can be compared to `onclick` or `addEventListener`. The handler should be stored and get called every time the value is changed. And, from my perspective, the third one is better.

Comment: IIFE isn’t very useful because it doesn’t hold any other locals; if used as shown, it also confuses the function name. Method 2 clobbers `constructor` and again has no advantage. An ES6 class is the way to go. And yes, your `on` implementation doesn’t work.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for reaching me out. Can you provide the code to let me know that what is the way to implement the on method? thanks

Comment: @obfish So what I need to do is to register an event and its handler, store in a object. And should have a method to fire the handler whenever the newModel was changed. Is that Right?

Comment: @obfish I just updated my ES6 code. Please let me know if any problem.

Comment: @Ry- I just updated my ES6 code. Please let me know if any problem.

Comment: @YizhiHong: `off` wasn’t part of the requirements, right? Also, the `if (!args || !args.length) args = [];` is redundant.

Comment: @Ry- Yes. But I think this question behind the scene is the observer architecture model, any subscriber should have a way to unsubscribe. It is more reliable to do so. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: looks good to me